# Storing line break in a php Variable

Tags: php, html, interface

I am developing a Facebook App in which I get some text from the Database and Display it on the Page.
The Problem is that I want to insert a line Break in the variable e-g
If I copy a Text from database and store it in a Variable..
    Let say
$text="I love to walk";

I want to insert a line break after "to" how can i do that?

```
I had tried to store the text like this in html 
"I love to <html> <br> </html> but that didn't worked..
```

Just suppose this is the Text ..may be next time the text is entirely Differnet having no "to" word.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have two options either use preg_replace or use a variable to save the value
please see php documentation for further info

Answer (score 3):

Depends on if you want to create new line in code output, or in HTML

```
$nl = "\r\n";
$nl_html = "<br />";
```

That exmple you provided modify like this:

```
$lyrics = "I love to <br> but that didn't worked.."
```

To automatically add line break after some text, use preg_replace

```
$lyrics = preg_replace('/to /',"to<br />",$lyrics);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Any **real** reason to use `preg_replace` in this case?

Comment: no, it's just my favorite way, you have any **real** reason to use str_replace?

Comment: but there might be a situation that There is no "to" word when i get values from database.

Comment: @Marek Sebera: `str_replace` is obviously simpler for CPU to perform. Any reason to overcomplicate solution when it is not necessary?

Comment: @Sharpzain: You need to rephrase your question then. Because "I want to insert a line break after "to"" makes no sense without "to" in the string

Comment: @Sharpzain this is just example, if you need to store new lines in DB when storing texts, you need to place `<br/>` in appropriate place in text, and store it inside DB, you can't push new lines in texts in such situation

Comment: @zerkms performance, but on the other hand preg_replace is more usable and handy than str_replace which is created for only purpose

Comment: @Marek Sebera: There is nothing handy and more usable in **this particular case**. Keep things as simple as it possible and everything will be fine ;-)

Comment: @Sharpzain: and what we have to suppose now? This **is** an answer to your **current** question. If the question asked is not what you actually thought about - rewrite it.

Comment: @ marek if I store text like this in "I love to <br/> walk" then how will i use the preg_replace function to insert a line break at appropriate place..

Comment: @Sharpzain: you won't have to use preg_replace if you will have line breaks already inserted to text, pre_replace/str_replace is only good when incoming data doesn't contain new lines

Comment: @marek I am using the variable in a php code..are you sure that just inserting <br/> will work out?

Comment: @marek I just tried that but that didn't worked.. "I love to <br/> walk"

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_str = str_replace('to', 'to <br />', $str, 1);
```

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\Image\index.php on line 17
That didn't worked...

Comment: @Sharpzain: it works. You made something wrong. Cannot say what actually until you show your exact code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the text in a html page, you need to make it

`$text="I love to <br /> walk";`

If you want to output it to a file you need to make it

`$text="I love to\r\nwalk";`
or
`$text="I love to\rwalk"`; depending on the OS on which you will be reading the file

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was having issues with this just as you do earlier today (I am new to PHP).

The way I fixed this was as follows:
$format_text = nl2br($formatthis);
You would then refer to $format_text.

What it does is it keeps the line breaks.

However I am not quite sure what you mean with your OP, after re-reading it. I went by the topic and I answered it as best I could.

If you are having trouble let's say echoing html code then most definitely you are having trouble with escaping characters.
For instance:
echo "a href="something" /a this won't work.

echo "a href=\"something\" /a this will work, notice the .